# How to allow for specific IPs to access rss feed urls in nginx?

Tags: nginx, rss

I want to restrict the access to rss feed urls like

```
 https://example.com/feed/20
```

and allow the access to specific IPs. I have done the following, but it didn't work.

```
        location ^~ /feed/ {
           allow 192.168.1.4;
           allow 192.168.1.5;
           deny all;
        }
```

Can any one has a best way to apply this?

Comment: Try changing location definition to this `location  /feed/ {...}`

Comment: It depends which `location` previously processed the request. The `location` in your question is missing any functionality other than returning a static file or 404. What does the rest of your `server` block look like?